# How to develop AppSync schemas using Apollo tools

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I'm using AppSync with Serverless and in the early phase of a new GraphQL implementation, that will eventually become rather large.

I've started off small, following the AWS recommended and published standards for [schema development](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/designing-your-schema.html).  My schema is starting to get larger and larger, and I'm left wanting better tools that I find are available in [Apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/generate-schema/#extending-types) (it appears that with Apollo, you can extend types, modularize, etc).

The schema development is static thus far -- you point serverless to a schema and thats it.  Is anyone aware of a library that supports an Apollo like environment (extending types, modular design, etc)?  Possibly something that compiles a schema, that I could point serverless to?  I have looked a little bit, but haven't really found anything that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found library that does this for me.  If you're in need, take a look at [graphql-s2s](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-s2s)

I was able to take the below schema, transpile it, save it, and point serverless to the generated schema.

Original:

```
    type TenantScope {
        tenantId: String
    }

    type Asset inherits TenantScope {
      type: String!
    }

    type Vehicle inherits Asset {
        vin: String!
        stockNum: String!
    }
```

Transpiled:

```
type TenantScope { 
    tenantId: String
}
type Asset { 
    type: String!
    tenantId: String
}
type Vehicle { 
    vin: String!
    stockNum: String!
    type: String!
    tenantId: String
}
```